# What is the typeArguments parameter of the Expression.Call Method when making a Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Currently I am trying to make an Expression Tree with MethodCallExpressions for When, Select and GroupBy. I started with [this manual on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) and several posts on StackOverflow. This gives us good examples to get started. To be able to write my own Expression Trees, without examples, I feel the need to understand the Expression.Call method with parameters as follows:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Expression instance,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
)
```

The third parameter is [described by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336138(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:

> An array of Type objects that specify the type parameters of the generic method. This argument should be null when methodName specifies a non-generic method.

This sounds rather general to me and I can't find out how to define which Type(s) I should pass with my Expression.Call method call.

Who can help me with a general explanation of the typeArguments parameter? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `typeArguments` parameter is used to call a generic method without giving the `MethodInfo`. Consider these functions for example:

```
public void NonGenericMethod() 
{
}

public void GenericMethod<T>()
{
}

public void GenericMethod2<T1, T2>()
{
}
```

For `NonGenericMethod` the `typeArguments` should be an empty array (use `Type.EmptyTypes`). `GenericMethod<T>` has **1 type argument**: the `typeArguments` should be an array with one `Type` (if you wanted to call `GenericMethod<int>`, it would be `new [] { typeof(int) }`). `GenericMethod2<T1, T2>` has **2 type arguments**: the `typeArguments` array should have two elements (`GenericMethod2<int, int>` would be `new [] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }` ). And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. Do I understand it correct that for example I pass the Types for the source and the key when calling the [Groupby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) method with Expression.Call?

Comment: @JorritSteetskamp That is correct. You need to pass an array of type that correspond to the types of `TSource` and `TKey`, in that order.

Answer (score 1):

A [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) is a method that has one or more type parameters. You create a generic method to apply an algorithm over a variety of types. For example:

```
public T DoSomething<T>(T input)
{
     return T; // do something useful
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
var result = DoSomething<int>(123);
```

In order to call a generic method, you have to specify the Type parameters. Therefore, you use the typeArguments argument in the Expression.Call method.